# Wicket 6.1 AjaxEventBehavior - how to set delay?

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

```
AjaxEventBehavior behavior = new AjaxEventBehavior("keyup"){

    @Override
    protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
};

form.add(behavior);
```

In previous versions of Wicket I could have done it like:

```
behavior.setThrottleDelay(Duration.ONE_SECOND);
```

But since version 6.1 this opportunity has been erased. And the web is full of previous versions tutorials which all contain .setThrottleDelay() methods.

Basically, the goal is to call out the behavior when the person has stopped typing in the form. Currently it calls out the behaviour every time INSTANTLY when the key gets up which basically spams the server side. That's why I would like to delay. Background: I'm currently trying to make queries into database and get out the data which are similar to the form input. And all that in the time when the person is typing. But the delay would be needed in goal to keep server-side/SQL out of the "bombarding range".

Also I am open to alternatives.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setting the throttle's settings has been unified with all other Ajax settings in AjaxRequestAttributes for version 6.0.0 which is a major version and was not drop-in replacement.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Wicket+Ajax contains a table with all the settings, the throttling ones are mentioned at the bottom of it.

To use it :

```
AjaxEventBehavior behavior = new AjaxEventBehavior("keyup") {

    @Override
    protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
    @Override
    protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes)
        super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);
        attributes.setThrottlingSettings(
            new ThrottlingSettings(id, Duration.ONE_SECOND, true)
        );
    }
};
```

The last constructor argument is what you need. Check its javadoc.

Comment: Your code example passes "id" as the first parameter on ThrottlingSettings - what is this variable?

Comment: I'm also puzzled by the 'id' parameter!!??

Comment: from Javadoc: This id is used by the client-side throttling code to keep track of the various event throttles. Normally you can just use any unique ID here, such as the component's markupId (`WebComponent#getMarkupId()`). To unite several different events with one throttle, give them the same ID.

Comment: Wicket 7 sets the component markup id automatically for you when you don't set the throttler id explicitly.

Comment: Please check your code, there seems to be a missing `{`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the sources, it looks as you can get the `AjaxRequestAttributes` via `getAttributes()` and call `setThrottlingSettings()` on this.

Strange that the api change is not mentioned in the wiki. The announcement for 6.1 calls it an drop in replacement.

Comment: This change has been done for 6.0.0 and it is described at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Wicket+Ajax (the extended migration page for Ajax).

Comment: @martin-g: thanks. the OP wrote that it was introduced in 6.1 (which would have been strange) and I did not check. Thanks for clearing that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [drop behavior](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxChannel.html) is what you're after:

> dropping - only the last Ajax request is processed, all previously
>   scheduled requests are discarded

You can specify a drop behavior, that will only  for the Ajax channel by customizing the [`AjaxRequestAttributes`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/attributes/AjaxRequestAttributes.html) of the behavior with [`AjaxChannel.DROP`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxChannel.html) by means of [`updateAjaxAttributes`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxEventBehavior.html#updateAjaxAttributes%28org.apache.wicket.ajax.attributes.AjaxRequestAttributes%29), as pointed out in the [wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/wicket-ajax.html#WicketAjax-AjaxRequestAttributes):

```
AjaxEventBehavior behavior = new AjaxEventBehavior("keyup"){

    @Override
    protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
    @Override
    protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes)
        super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);
        attributes.setChannel(new AjaxChannel("myChannel", AjaxChannel.Type.DROP));
    }
};

form.add(behavior);
```

As @bert also suggested, you can also [`setThrottlingSettings`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/attributes/AjaxRequestAttributes.html#setThrottlingSettings%28org.apache.wicket.ajax.attributes.ThrottlingSettings%29) to the `AjaxRequestAttributes`.

Probably a combination of both behaviors would fit better in what you seem to need.

Comment: getAttributes() is the final method from AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior and I can't override it. By reading the source I as well found out the setThrottlingSettings via AjaxFormValidatingBehavior, but back then and now as well it gives me an error(overriding issue).

Comment: You're right, the override should be on [updateAjaxAttributes](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxEventBehavior.html#updateAjaxAttributes(org.apache.wicket.ajax.attributes.AjaxRequestAttributes)) instead, as pointed out in the [wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/wicket-ajax.html#WicketAjax-AjaxRequestAttributes). I've updated the answer

Comment: DROP cannot be resolved or is not a field. Even though AjaxChanne.Type shows "DROP". 
`@Override
protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes){    ThrottlingSettings throttlingSettings = new   ThrottlingSettings("throttle",Duration.ONE_SECOND); attributes.setThrottlingSettings(throttlingSettings); attributes.setChannel(AjaxChannel.DROP); 
}`

Now when I get keyup in the form, then it waits for one second and gives output "Hello world!" if I type again then it wouldn't do that again.

Really sorry Xavi for bothering you, but the web is really empty on this subject. :)

Comment: Actually you need to construct a new `AjaxChannel` using its constructor. Provide a name and `AjaxChannel.Type.DROP` to it. I'm also sorry, I've never used this (used to override AjaxBehavior's `getChannelName()` to return `0|d` back in Wicket 1.3), and didn't test the code to be working right away.

Comment: Thanks, Xavi, now with this error it's okay. But any further ideas with the problem where it calls out onEvent() only once?

Comment: Do you see any trace of what can be happening in the Wicket Ajax Debug console?

Comment: I found out later that I somehow deleted super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes); Anyway, Xavi, thank you very much for the help and contribution.